# Flutter Project Bundle ID Update Not Reflected in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I am working on a Flutter project and recently updated my iOS bundle ID from `com.example.myappid` to `com.mycompany.myapp`. However, I'm facing an issue where this change is not being reflected in App Store Connect.

The app have never been uploaded on App Store Connect before, and I am trying to add new app.

Here are the ways I tried:

1. Changed the bundle ID in Xcode.
2. Cleaned and rebuilt the project in Flutter.
3. Remove old Identifier and create new one

Despite these steps, the App Store Connect page still shows the old bundle ID. I am looking for guidance on how to ensure that the new bundle ID is recognized by App Store Connect.

NOT TRYING TO CHANGE ALREADY UPLOADED APP ID, I AM TRYING TO ADD NEW APP. And in the Bundle ID dropdown, new ID doesn't appear.

Tried to create an Identifier myself, but it shows `An App ID with Identifier <id> is not available. Please enter a different string.`.
the id is TOO UNIQUE, so I don't think it's already taken, but is there any way to check whether it's taken?

Is there a step I'm missing or a common issue that could be causing this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In case bundle ID is not updated (with automatically manage signing marked), you can normally go to [developer page](https://developer.apple.com/account/) to create a new bundle. Then go to AppStoreConnect and register a new app with that bundle.

Comment: @son I treid to create a new bundle, it says `An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value` with `An App ID with Identifier <id> is not available. Please enter a different string`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like someone else might take this bundle or your Provisioning might be expired.

Comment: You need to create a new app record in App Store Connect with your new bundle ID. There is no way that App Store Connect can know that the bundle you are updating (with a new bundle ID) is a replacement of your app with a different bundle id. Essentially, the bundle ID *is* the app.

Comment: I don't think someone else already took it because the bundle id is TOO unique tho. and I am trying to add an app in App Store Connect, but cannot find the new bundle ID to fill the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem solved

Since the ID was registered in my personal account but I didn't upload the actual app, I was able to register the ID normally in my company account after it was deregistered from my personal account after the expiration date.